# How to convert Hangul letter(symbol) to latin

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

Language could be java.

This is what I would like to accomplish:

[image]

Basically, print out the pronunciation of the Hangul written word.

Comment: A solution to this problem requires some knowledge of Hangul.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to google for solution - had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is very broad and deals with the transliteration
of the Hangul letters.

Searching Google for the topic you can find:

- [Hong's Hangul Conversion Tools](http://sori.org/hangul/conv2kr.cgi) which describes the common accepted rules for the transliteration

and a project (sadly written  in PERL) hosted on Google Code:

- [conv2kr](https://code.google.com/p/conv2kr/)  which applies said rules

Comment: Thank you Carlo. This seems to be the best resource out there. Thank you for your effort.